# Iterate over array in shell whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop

Let us say, i have an array: 
`versions=(1 2 3 4)`
I can iterate over it by :
`for i in ${versions[@]}`
How to do this if the name of the array is decided on the basis of some other variable, hence stored in a variable
Example:

```
array_name=${some_var}_arr

declare -a ${array_name}
```

How do I iterate over elements of array whose name is stored in array_name.
I tried

```
for i in ${${array_name}[@]}
```

Got bad substitution error

Comment: thanks @MarkReed, got the solution at the  link